# Logarithm derivative of $ \zeta(s) $

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I have just proved that

$$- \frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \sum\limits_p\frac{\log(p)}{p^s - 1}$$ and am aiming to prove that

$$ -\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \sum\limits_p\frac{\log(p)}{p^s} + h(s) $$

with $ h $ being a holomorphic function on $ \Re(s) > 0 $.

I have calculated that $ h(s) = \sum\limits_p \frac{\log(p)}{p^s(p^s-1)} $. I just don't know how to prove that it is holomorphic there - I'm not very familiar with complex analysis and I crossed this mooching around "analytic number theory".

I'd appreciate some help

Comment: Actually, $h$ is only holomorphic for $\Re s > \frac{1}{2}$. Do you know how to argue that $h$ is holomorphic for $\Re s > \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Well, probably it's enought that the series is convergent. But something similar applies to the zeta function itself; it is defined on $ \Re(z) > 1 $, but somehow we consider it on the half-plane $ \Re(z) > 0 $, where it is holomorphic

Comment: Depends on what you mean with "convergent". Pointwise convergence is not enough, but locally uniform convergence is, and we have locally uniform convergence on $\Re s > \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: The $\zeta$-function has an analytic continuation to a meromorphic function on the whole plane with a single pole at $1$. I don't know whether $h$ has an analytic continuation across the line $\Re s = \frac{1}{2}$ anywhere, but at $s = \frac{1}{2}$, there is a singularity, since $$\lim_{s \searrow \frac{1}{2}} h(s) = +\infty.$$